# FacebookDialog to post photo returns postid is null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am running the android facebook SDK sample HelloFacebookSample  (sdk-version-3.19), modified to print out the postID

postId is always null, any ideas why ?

```
@@ -32,7 +32,9 @@ import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
+
import com.facebook.*;
+import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphPlace;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
@@ -93,6 +95,8 @@ public class HelloFacebookSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
             Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
+            String postId = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogPostId(data);
+            Log.i("dialogCallback", "::enclosing_method:" + " postId="+ postId );
         }
     };
```

Comment: Just because this dialog callback is getting called does not mean its a success.

Comment: the photo gets posted to facebook and FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogDidComplete, FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogCompletionGesture  return the right results